# Plotting: one label for two curves

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

Consider the following code

```
styles = {Red, Blue, {Red, Dashed}, {Blue, Dashed}}
pt1 = Plot[{x^2, 2 x^2, 1/x^2, 2/x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, 
PlotStyle -> styles, PlotLegends -> {"1", "2", "1", "2"}]
```

I would like the two red lines to carry the same label "1" and the two blue lines the same label "2". That is, in the legend I would like a red line and a red-dashed line below each other and then one label right of it. Similarly for the blue lines. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Will you always have one solid and one dashed line for each group, or is that only an example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard For what I need currently, they are always grouped together with two. However, I would be interested in knowing how the general case works.

Answer (score 7):

```
ClearAll[table]
table[pairs_] := Module[{p = pairs}, p[[3, 2]] = SpanFromAbove; 
  p[[4, 2]] = SpanFromAbove; Grid[p[[{1, 3, 2, 4}]], Alignment -> {Center, Center}]]; 

styles = {Red, Blue, {Red, Dashed}, {Blue, Dashed}};
pt1 = Plot[{x^2, 2 x^2, 1/x^2, 2/x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> styles, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, {"1", "2", "1", "2"}, LegendLayout -> table]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I know I am nitpicking here, but is there any way to make the vertical spacing between the two red lines smaller, while keeping the distance between the dashed red and the solid blue line constant?

Comment: kglr, since we ended up with similar answers shall I edit yours to include my variation, and delete mine?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I think you should keep your answer; it is cleaner and also, addressing the spacing question, more complete.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like kglr beat me to it but I was also working on a `LegendLayout` method, so here it is.

```
styles = {Red, {Red, Dashed}, Blue, {Blue, Dashed}};

pair = (Grid[{Column @ #[[All, 1]], #[[1, 2]]} & /@ Partition[#, 2]] &);

Plot[{x^2, 1/x^2, 2 x^2, 2/x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> styles, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   LineLegend[styles, {"1", "1", "2", "2"}, 
    LegendLayout -> pair]]
```

[image]

I chose to reorder the expressions and styles as that seemed simpler to me, but I suppose a Transpose at the right point would have worked too.

---

Directly borrowing ideas from kglr's answer:

```
styles = {Red, {Red, Dashed}, Blue, {Blue, Dashed}};

pair = Grid[MapAt[SpanFromAbove &, #, {2 ;; ;; 2, 2}], 
    Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Spacings -> {1/2, {{1, -0.5}}}] &;

Plot[{x^2, 1/x^2, 2 x^2, 2/x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> styles, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[styles, {"1", "1", "2", "2"}, LegendLayout -> pair]]
```

[image]